# want keep always webpage position on after reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I am building a webpage. I want to keep page position always on top after reload but this is not happening. If my current scrol positin is X then again webpage position remains in position X after reloading. How to solve it ?

Comment: Doaes this happen in all browsers?

Comment: i have found the problem. Its not for coding. happening in all browser and not only my webpage. Every website is affected in chrome or firefox. what can be the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript scrollTo method to scroll on 0,0 position of page.

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

Be sure to keep this line of code inside document ready event / page load event or on last of page as browser scroll to previous location after the page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Set `maintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` in web.config.

Comment: Surely that will only work when for `POST` requests?

Comment: i have found the problem. Its not for coding. happening in all browser and not only my webpage. Every website is affected in chrome or firefox. what can be the solution ?